# Uniformly Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A random variable X drawn from a uniform [0,3] distribution and a random variable y is independently drawn randomly drawn from a uniform [0,4] distribution. The joint probability density f(x,y) is also uniform, with support given by 0 ≤ x ≤ 3, 0 ≤ y ≤ 4. Find the probability for the sum of two randomly selected number is 3
This should be 0 because a line does not have any area, right?
Find the probability for the sum of two randomly selected number  greater than 3
12-4.5 = 7.5, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabilities are between $0$ and $1$, so you should be able to spot that $7.5$ is certainly wrong.

Try dividing by the total area of your rectangle.

Comment: is it going to be 7.5/12 = .625? Also, find the probability for the sum of two randomly selected number is 3. This should be 0 because a line does not have any area, right?

Comment: That is what I think.